# Is there a complete uncountable theory with two countable models?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

*This is a [question originally asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250951/does-any-uncountable-complete-theory-have-exactly-two-countable-models) a few years ago; the original poster hasn't been active in a while, so I'm taking the liberty of asking it here:*

> Is there a complete first-order theory $T$ with exactly two countable models up to isomorphism?

If we require $T$ to be countable the answer is negative (Vaught's "Never-Two" theorem). However, the proof of this breaks down completely once we allow $T$ to be uncountable. Various cardinality-mixing results are comparatively easy - e.g. there is a *countable* theory with exactly two models of *cardinality $\aleph_1$* up to isomorphism - but none of them (that I'm aware of anyways) bear on this question.

Comment: Nice question .

Comment: Gabe Conant pointed out that MSE question to me a while ago and in thinking about it, I started to think that a more tractable related question would be this: Is there an expansion of $(\mathbb{N},+,\cdot)$ that has a unique countable elementary extension up to isomorphism? (There are some results about uncountable language expansion of $\mathbb{N}$ that might be useful here.) I wasn't able to resolve it and I was considering asking it on MO, but I never got around to it.

Comment: Also, fun fact: A countable complete theory cannot have precisely $4$ models (up to isomorphism) of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @JamesHanson The fact in your second comment is neat, do you have a citation for that? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007199) is a modern reference (with a full classification of the spectra of countable theories). I was under the impression that the result was originally due to Lachlan, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @JamesHanson and Noah: the original reference is [Theories with a finite number of models in  an uncountable power are categorical](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-61/issue-2/Theories-with-a-finite-number-of-models-in-an-uncountable/pjm/1102868040.pdf) by Lachlan. I don't think he makes the remark about $4$ there, but it follows from the proof.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Do you know a complete classification of which finite numbers can occur as the number of models of size $\aleph_1$? This (and the analogous question for $\aleph_n$ in general) seems like it might be a kind of tough combinatorics problem.

Comment: @JamesHanson No, I haven't thought about it. You're right that the Lachlan result reduces it to a pure finite combinatorics / group theory problem. I don't know how tricky it is.

Comment: After some offline discussion, James and I realized that for any finite $k$, there is a countable theory with exactly $k$ models of size $\aleph_1$ up to isomorphism: take the theory of an equivalence relation with exactly $k$ classes, each of which is infinite. Then a model of size $\aleph_1$ is determined up to isomorphism by how many of the classes are uncountable. However, there is no countable theory with exactly $4$ models of size $\aleph_2$ up to isomorphism. Other numbers which cannot be realized in $\aleph_2$ include $2$, $8$, and $9$ (assuming I've done my computations correctly).

Comment: Similarly, the only numbers less than $20$ that occur as the number of models of size $\aleph_3$ for some countable theory are: $1$, $4$, $7$, $10$, and $13$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman That's wild! Is (say) the set of $(m,n)$ such that there is a countable complete theory with exactly $m$ isomorphism classes of size-$\aleph_n$ models known to be computable?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I believe it is computable - if you ask this as a separate question, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @AlexKruckman ['Tis done.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454110/is-the-set-of-permissible-numbers-of-models-of-various-cardinalities-computable)

Comment: An answer to the question has been posted on MSE. [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4808176/7062)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted an example of such a theory over as math.stackexchange.com: [Does any uncountable complete theory have exactly two countable models?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808176)
I'll avoid copying the whole thing, in case there are corrections to be made, but here's the summary:

> Yes, this is possible. I'll describe an uncountable language $\mathcal L$ and two non-isomorphic elementarily equivalent countable $\mathcal L$-structures $M_0,M_1$ such that any other elementarily equivalent countable structure is isomorphic to one of these. The idea is that $M_0$ encodes the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ of even order, and $M_1$ encodes the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ of odd order, but the language doesn't distinguish which is which.